# Accessing the contents of Map<Long, Map<String, Object>> in jsp using key value

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I have a jsp page that receives a HashMap object of this type:
`Map<Long, Map<String, Object>>`.

An example of this map would be: 
 `foo = {1 = {id=1, response="someText"}, 2={id=99, response="random"}};`

I am trying to iterate over the contents of both maps in foo like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${fooMap.content}" var="outerMap">
    <c:forEach items="${outerMap.value}" var = "innerMap">
        <p>${innerMap.response}</p>
    </c:foreach>
</c:forEach>
```

But this throws "Property 'response' not found on type java.util.HashMap.....
Would someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

I know that I can access the contents of innerMap using Map.EntrySet. But I want to access the value using specific keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `${outerMap.value}` returns a `Map<String, Object>` of which one entry has "response" as key. So you need to get it straight from there instead of iterating over its entryset in `${innerMap}`.

```html
<c:forEach items="${fooMap.content}" var="outerMap">
    <p>${outerMap.value.response}</p>
</c:forEach>
```

An (more clumsy) alternative is checking the `${innerMap}` entry key:

```html
<c:forEach items="${fooMap.content}" var="outerMap">
    <c:forEach items="${outerMap.value}" var="innerMap">
        <c:if test="${innerMap.key == 'response'}">
            <p>${innerMap.value}</p>
        </c:if>
    </c:foreach>
</c:forEach>
```

Can you now still wrap your head around it? :)

Comment: Thank you very much. That just nailed it. Would you mind telling me why my approach was wrong? I figured since foo is map of maps. I would iterate twice and access the keys and values.

Comment: The `${outerMap}` is a `Map.Entry` whose value is the inner map. To get a value by key, you need a handle to the inner map. But you attempted to get a value by key on the `Map.Entry` of the inner map, which indeed doesn't have a `getResponse()` method. It has only `getKey()` and `getValue()` methods.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the answer. I will accept your answer as soon as SO allows me to do so.